# How to pass parameter to another page and print the content

Tags: javascript, iframe, printing

I am going to print a page without loading that page. As I searched in stack overflow I found the following example the best.

But the problem here is that I cannot pass any parameter using the `src` attribute.

Now, I am looking for a way to pass a ***parameter*** to an ***external page*** and then ***print*** that page without loading that page.

If anyone can help me I will be thankful but please do not mark my question as a duplicated question.

```
<html> 
<head> 
<title>Index</title> 
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.3.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#loaderFrame').load(function(){
        var w = (this.contentWindow || this.contentDocument.defaultView);
        w.print();
    });

    $('#printerButton').click(function(){
        $('#loaderFrame').attr('src', 'print.php');
    });
});
</script>
<style>
 #loaderFrame{
    visibility: hidden;
    height: 1px;
    width: 1px;
 }
 </style>
 </head> 
 <body> 
 <input type="button" id="printerButton" name="print" value="Print It" />

 <iframe id="loaderFrame" ></iframe>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: Why don't you store that data in ```sessionStorage``` or in ```localStorage``` and then use the stored data in your ***External Page*** for printing.

Comment: Good idea. But I want to receive that data as POST or GET variable in external page.